# How can I prevent Incorrect format parameter in Mamp phpMyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp-pro

I am working with MampPro 6.2 with php version 7.4.9

I try to import a database but I get a phpmyadmin error:

> Incorrect format parameter

So in my Mamp application I changed File>Open Template>PHP (php.ini)>7.4.9:

```
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize=2G
post_max_size=2G
```

And I started the server again.
I tried to upload the database again but still the same error.

Comment: *I try to import a database* What do you do precisely? Import database dump (.SQL) file?

Comment: I am uploading a file `database.sql`

Comment: Have you tested this dump? Does it can be imported via CLI?

Comment: yes, it is a valid sql file

Comment: I had the same issue a while ago, never fully understood what was going on BUT got it fixed. What i did was download the TABLES instead of the database itself, then i re-created the database and imported the tables.

Comment: @Minnen This solution is difficult for me. Because I often have to download the newest sql file from another server and upload it into my local phpmyadmin. This would be too much work to download everytime every single table

Comment: I understand, i realize my solution is not optimal and i would like to encourage others monitoring this question to provide an ACTUAL solution for this as i myself STILL have this issue from time to time BUT this could get you out of a 'hurry', best of luck buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is:

I am working with different hosts in Mamp Pro, and after I changed the php version of localhost to the same php version than my host, it worked.

Probably although the import works now you might have another error like this

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.

A solution for this you can find here:

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro